# Combine Two Values from Two JQuery Functions

Tags: jquery

I am trying to combine the count of two different checkbox groups and come up with the total number of checkboxes between the them. However when I put the variables cnt and cnt1 outside the respective functions it adds the number of checkedboxes instead of counting them.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            var countTotal = 0;
            var cnt = 0;
            var cnt1 = 0;

            $('input[name="chkSelect"]').click(function () {
                updateNumber('chkSelect');
            });

            $('input[name="chkSelect1"]').click(function () {
                updateNumber1('chkSelect1');
            });

            var updateNumber = function () {
                var result = $('input[name="chkSelect"]:checked');
                var countedgroupno = [];
                result.each(function () {
                var group = $(this).attr('group');
                var lastletter = group.substr(group.length-1, 1);
                if(lastletter.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
                    group = group.substring(0, group.length-1);
                }
                    if ($.inArray(group, countedgroupno) == -1) {
                        cnt++;
                        countedgroupno.push(group);
                    }
                });
                $('#countCK').val(cnt);
            };

            var updateNumber1 = function () {
                var result = $('input[name="chkSelect1"]:checked');
                var countedgroupno = [];
                result.each(function () {
                    var group = $(this).attr('group');
                    var lastletter = group.substr(group.length - 1, 1);
                    if (lastletter.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
                        group = group.substring(0, group.length - 1);
                    }
                    if ($.inArray(group, countedgroupno) == -1) {
                        cnt1++;
                        countedgroupno.push(group);
                    }
                });
                $('#countCK1').val(cnt1);
            };
            var countTotal = cnt * cnt1
           $('#TotalcountCK').val(countTotal); 
        });
<form id="form1" runat="server">
                <br />
                Count Group 1: <input type="text" id="countCK" />
                <br />
                Count Group 2: <input type="text" id="countCK1" />
                <br />             
        Total Count: <input type="text" id="TotalcountCK" />
       <br />
  <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="height: 75px; width: 400px">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <label><%# Eval("DeptName") %></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkSelect" value='<%# Eval("DeptGroup") %>' group='<%# Eval("DeptGroup") %>'/>
        <br />     
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate> 
   </asp:Repeater>

  <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table style="height: 75px; width: 400px">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <label><%# Eval("EmpName") %></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkSelect1" value='<%# Eval("EmpGroup") %>' group='<%# Eval("EmpGroup") %>'/>
        <br />     
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate> 
   </asp:Repeater>             
</form>
```

Comment: what? I can't quite get what you want

Comment: I have two different groups of checkboxes. I need to find the total number of checked boxes between the two groups.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: Cant you just use something like: `$('input[name="chkSelect"]:checked, input[name="chkSelect1"]:checked').length;`?

Comment: @DBS I tried that but no luck.